# Convert a collection of objects with a string property to an enumeration of those strings using LINQ

Tags: linq, ienumerable, observablecollection, predicate

I have an IEnumerable object where Foo has a string property called 'Name'.  Is there an easy LINQ statement that will let me return a collection of strings from that enumeration for those names?

e.g.

```
IEnumerable<Foo> (which contains...)
    Foo.Name = First
    Foo.Name = Second
    Foo.Name = Third
```

I want to return an IEnumerable that contains 'First', 'Second' and 'Third'

Howdoyadoozat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your initial IEnumerable is called list, this will do it:

```
list.Select(f => f.Name);
```

Comment: Bingo!  Exactly what I wanted.  Just out of curiosity, if it had been list.select(f => f.Name == "Joe") would that have returned a collection of Foo objects with Name equal to "Joe" (assuming there was one or more that did) or would it instead return a collection of booleans? After all, f.Name returns a string while f.Name == "Joe" returns a boolean so I'm not sure.  That's what throws me... I don't know what Select returns.  I always thought it returned a collection of 'f's but you just proved otherwise.

Comment: list.Select(f => f.Name == "Joe") would return an IEnumerable of bools, if you only wanted those Foos that have name "Joe" you want list.Where(f => f.Name == "Joe") and if you only wanted the strings which equal "Joe" you want list.Where(f => f.Name == "Joe").Select(f => f.Name)

Comment: And that's why I voted you up!  Awesome!  That makes so much more sense now and is completely clear. It's pretty much just chained functions.  Awesomage!  Thanks!